# Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character', how do I fix this?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm following this tutorial: https://appsilon.com/shiny-fluent-tutorial/ and
I ran into this error : Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'. this error wasn't present until using the router library.

Could anyone help? I'm also having the issue of not being able to navigate to the home page

server code

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_deals <- reactive({
    req(input$fromDate)
    selectedPeople <- (
      if (length(input$selectedPeople) > 0) input$selectedPeople
      else fluentPeople$key
    )
    minClosedVal <- if (isTRUE(input$closedOnly)) 1 else 0
    
    filtered_deals <- fluentSalesDeals %>%
      filter(
        rep_id %in% selectedPeople,
        date >= input$fromDate,
        date <= input$toDate,
        deal_amount >= input$slider,
        is_closed >= minClosedVal
      ) %>%
      mutate(is_closed = ifelse(is_closed == 1, "Yes", "No"))
  })
  
  output$analysis <- renderUI({
    items_list <- if(nrow(filtered_deals()) > 0){
      DetailsList(items = filtered_deals(), columns = details_list_columns)
    } else {
      p("No matching transactions.")
    }
    
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(filtered_deals(), aes(x = rep_name)) + 
      geom_bar( fill =unique(filtered_deals()$color)) +
      ylab("Number of deals") +
      xlab ("Sales rep") +
      theme_light()
    ggplotly(p,height = 300)
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    points <- cbind(filtered_deals()$LONGITUDE, filtered_deals()$LATITUDE)
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
      addMarkers(data = points)
  })
    Stack(
      tokens = list(childrenGap = 10), horizontal = TRUE,
      makeCard("Top results", div(style="max-height: 500px; overflow: auto", items_list)),
      makeCard("Map", leafletOutput("map"))
    )
    
router$server(input, output, session)
  })}
```

Didn't find any solutions

Comment: If you remove `filtered_deals <- ` within your reactive call, what happens? To be clear, you are not specifying what the reactive object is returning, that could be the problem.

Comment: If I remove filtered_deals. Everything was working as intended until I added the shiny router

Comment: The `filtered_deals <-` within the reactive is fine: the `<-` assignment operator by default returns (invisibly) the value assigned, so having it or not, the result from `. %>% filter(..) %>% mutate(..)` is going to be the value returned from that encasing `reactive`. Granted, if you have `filtered_deals <- ...`, then it seems more _declarative_ to then have a solitary `filtered_deals` at the end, but that's completely a subjective thing as far as code-progression goes.

Comment: found the issue after reading through the shiny.router documentation, no idea why it works, but moved router$server(input, output, session) to the first line of server code.



First couple lines now read 
server <- function(input, output, session) 
  
  
{
  router$server(input, output, session)
  
  filtered_deals <- reactive({
    req(input$fromDate)